# Merging Rows Based Similar Fields - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Although I am able to create pivot tables in excel, I would like to use Python to ultimately combine rows with similar fields. In this case, the row should be combined with the same "id" and "location" only.

Input:

```
id  location    date        code
111 Park        1/1/2018    7765
143 School      2/5/2018    3345
111 Beach       1/1/2018    7534
223 Library     3/5/2018    3345
```

Output 1:

```
id  location      date      code
111 Park, Beach   1/1/2018  7765, 7534
143 School        2/5/2018  3345
223 Library       3/5/2018  3345
```

Output 2:

```
id  location1     location2   date      code1    code2
111 Park          Beach       1/1/2018  7765     7534
143 School                    2/5/2018  3345
223 Library                   3/5/2018  3345
```

The only reason why I would like understand the queries for both outputs is because I have multiple other columns with definitions for these codes. I know I should use groupby ID and location, however, I am having difficulty with the merge in output 1 and with output 2 with the creation of the new rows.

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? also you want to combine by `id` and `date`, Right?

Comment: Correct, pandas df. And I would only like to combine if `id` and `date` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

### Approach 1

Join the necessary columns in dataframe

```
df["code"] = df["code"].astype(str)
output1 = df.groupby("id").agg({"location": ",".join,"code":",".join,"date":'first'}).reset_index()
```

### Approach 2

In this approach, If person A goes to the School twice on the same day, the output will take unique values as `School` instead of showing `School, School`. At the same, let's say person A goes to the School twice on the same day but has two different code, then it produce both `School,School`

```
df["code"] = df["code"].astype(str)
output1 = df.groupby(["id","date"]).agg({"location": list,"code":list}).reset_index()

## check location and code having same set of unique values, will be performing `set` operation take unique elements
unique_values = output1[output1["location"].apply(set).apply(len) == output1["code"].apply(set).apply(len)]
## check location and code having different set of unique values, this case, might have same location with two different dates,
## no need to take `set` operation for this
other_values = output1[output1["location"].apply(set).apply(len) != output1["code"].apply(set).apply(len)]

## convert to set to , separated
unique_values["location"] = unique_values["location"].apply(set).apply(",".join)
unique_values["code"] = unique_values["code"].apply(set).apply(",".join)

other_values["location"] = other_values["location"].apply(",".join)
other_values["code"] = other_values["code"].apply(",".join)

## join both the dataframe
output1 = pd.concat([unique_values, other_values]).sort_index()
```

this produce `output1` dataframe

[image]

The below code is for expanding the `location` and `code` column in dataframe,

```
output2 = output1["location"].str.split(pat=",",expand=True)
output2.columns = ["location_"+ str(i) for i in output2.columns] 
output3 = output1["code"].str.split(pat=",",expand=True)
output3.columns = ["code"+ str(i) for i in output3.columns] 
final_output = pd.concat([output1, output2, output3],axis=1)
final_output = final_output.fillna('')
```

Final output is

[image]

Comment: One question, how would you adapt the code in order to avoid have the same location repeated twice? For example, if person A goes to the School twice on the same day, the output is showing `School,School`.  I would like that to show as `School` only in that case. However, let's say person A goes to the School twice on the same day but has two different `code`. Then the output should be School,School. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, I am noticing duplicates in the sense of person A going to the `Park,School` or `School,Park.` Is there an order by operation I should use to ensure so that does not occur?

Comment: @Logan, I have updated the solution. For removing duplicates you may need to perform `drop_duplicates`. But, I have handled the situation where the person goes `School` twice on same day with different codes.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
mapper = lambda x : ",".join(x)
df["code"] = df["code"].astype(str)    
df.groupby("id").agg({"location" : mapper, "code" : mapper})

         location         code
id                            
111      Park,Beach     7765,7534
143        School         3345
223       Library         3345
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(by=['id', 'date'], as_index=False).agg({'location': ','.join, 'code': ','.join})
print(df)

    id       date    location       code
0  111 2018-01-01  Park,Beach  7765,7534
1  143 2018-02-05      School       3345
2  223 2018-03-05     Library       3345
```

Answer (score 1):

For CASE 1 use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `id and date` then aggregate the `location and code` column to using `.join`:

```
df1 = df.astype({'code': 'str'}).groupby(['id', 'date']).agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

For CASE 2, use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `id and variable` and use a transformation using `cumcount` to add a sequential counter to `variable` column, finally use `.set_index`, `unstack`, `droplevel`.

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'date'])
df2['variable'] += df2.groupby(['id', 'variable']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'date', 'variable']).unstack().droplevel(0, 1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
# CASE 1: print(df1)
    id      date     location        code
0  111  1/1/2018  Park, Beach  7765, 7534
1  143  2/5/2018       School        3345
2  223  3/5/2018      Library        3345

# CASE 2: print(df2)
variable   id      date code1 code2 location1 location2
0         111  1/1/2018  7765  7534      Park     Beach
1         143  2/5/2018  3345   NaN    School       NaN
2         223  3/5/2018  3345   NaN   Library       NaN
```